# add vertical line intersecting 3 different axes in a figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have to plot eeg data of 3 different channels in my graph. I would like to plot of all of them in one figure seperated by horozintal lines. X axis common to all the channels.

I can do this easily by using add_axes. But i want to draw a vertical line intersecting these axes. But i m not able to do it.

Currently, my sample code look like this.

```
from pylab import figure, show, setp
from numpy import sin, cos, exp, pi, arange

t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s1 = sin(2*pi*t)
s2 = exp(-t)
s3 = 200*t



fig = figure()
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

yprops = dict(rotation=0,
              horizontalalignment='right',
              verticalalignment='center',
              x=-0.1)

axprops = dict(yticks=[])

ax1 =fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.2], **axprops)
ax1.plot(t, s1)
ax1.set_ylabel('S1', **yprops)

axprops['sharex'] = ax1
#axprops['sharey'] = ax1
# force x axes to remain in register, even with toolbar navigation
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2], **axprops)

ax2.plot(t, s2)
ax2.set_ylabel('S2', **yprops)

ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.2], **axprops)
ax3.plot(t, s3)
ax3.set_ylabel('S3', **yprops)




# turn off x ticklabels for all but the lower axes
for ax in ax1, ax2:
    setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

show()
```

I want my final image to look like the one below. In my current output, i can get the same graph without the green vertical line.

[image]

can any one please help ???    I dont want to use subplots and also i dont want to add axvline for each axes.

Thank u,
thothadri

Answer (score 1):

use

```
vl_lst = [a.axvline(x_pos, color='g', lw=3, linestyle='-') for a in [ax1, ax2, ax3]]
```

to update for each frame:

```
new_x = X
for v in vl_lst:
    v.set_xdata(new_x)
```

[`axvline` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline)

Comment: Actually, i know that works . But I dont want to seperately add for each sub axes.

Comment: Because, I m trying to animate the green line in the x-axis at a velocity of .33 seconds. So everytime, I have to draw seperate line for each axes and it may cause more computation power

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh Artists are attached to axes.  Drawing across three axes with a single artist seems dicey to me.

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh Don't try to optimize till you are sure it is a problem;)

Comment: But still i hope there should be some way. I also tried creating another axes from [.1 .1 .8 .7 ]. But it replaced  the other three.

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh Is the animation too slow?  If yes, then ask a question with the details of that, if no, don't worry about it until it is too slow.  Why do you expect that using a 4th axes object (a heavy object that needs to be fully rendered) would be faster than updating three lines (which are lightweight objects and it can be optimized greatly via `blit`)?

Comment: Yes, Now I am able to understand you. I have tried animation with one axes.  NOw i add the data and tell you how the performance is.